# Why doesn't xdg-open trigger autoread?

Tags: external-command

When `set autoread`，if I run `:!kate %`, do some editing operations and exit, the file in vim will auto reload to my new changes. However, `:!xdg-open %` doesn't work.

My vim version is: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you please clarify why you expect how executing `xdg-open` "doesn't work"? Is it not opening the file in an external program at all? Or is it opening it in an external program, but after you modify the file with the external program, Vim doesn't display it as modified? Did you mention `kate` because that's what `xdg-open` will open it in?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague, but I'm assuming when you use `:!xdg-open %`it will *also* open the current file in the `kate` editor, but when you do so, after you close `kate`, Vim will not detect that the file has changed.

I'm guessing what is happening here is that the file association entry that `xdg-open` is using to open `kate` is doing so in background (e.g. it's executing `kate "$1" &` or similar.) You can confirm that by switching back to Vim and checking whether it's blocked waiting for the launched program to finish or not.

If that's indeed what is happening, then it would explain the difference in behavior. Since launching `:!kate %` will wait for the external program to finish, Vim will check the file for changes then and there, before going back to editing the file.

When the program is launched in background, Vim will not wait for a notification that the external program is finished, so it needs some further action to actually go check whether the file was changed by an external program or not.

You can use the [`:checktime`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Achecktime) command to have Vim check whether the file has been modified outside Vim.

(Note also that launching a program in background is actually a configuration of the file association in `xdg-open`, so redefining that particular association to launch the program in foreground is potentially another option to resolve this issue.)